# Does dplyr perform caching on disk under the hood?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a (Windows) machine with 32GB of RAM. Furthermore, let's say I have two heavy data frames, d1 which takes 15GB of RAM, and d2 which takes 10GB of RAM.

If I try to do a dplyr::full_join() on them:

```
d1 = full_join(d1, d2, copy = FALSE)
```

will dplyr try to use the disk for caching, when it has exhausted all of the available RAM?

P.S.
I know lots of people prefer "<-" to "=", but it (almost) always works fine for me, the only exception being in a system.time() call.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: Definitely not! R works in volatile memory, which is why calculations are expedient.  A down side of this construction is that when you are working on data frames, copying, merging them, the exist in their original & their final states ( and sometimes the even have intermediate stages) existing in live active memory. If you would like to work in hard memory, you will need to explicitly write code to manage the data/files properly.